# After using amnah authentication the backend crud of user module shows the Yii2 User Module not the User CRUD

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

We've been working on a project with Yii2 Advanced App, with a custom bootstrap template. I've generated the crud using gii. All other CRUDs work fine. But the User crud displays Yii2 User Module not the CRUD.

I've gone through amnah's complete documentations and couldn't find any solutions in any other places either. I even tried Yii2 documentations and it wasn't any help either.

This is my backend config

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

return [
'id' => 'app-backend',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
'defaultRoute' => 'sahasa/index',
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ],
    'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
    ],
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'amnah\yii2\user\components\User',
    ],
    // 'user' => [
    //     'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
    //     'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    // ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
],
'params' => $params,
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'amnah\yii2\user\Module',
        // set custom module properties here ...
    ],
    'debug' => [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ],
],
];
```

This is what I get when I goto `localhost/app/backend/web/index.php?r=user`

[image]

I want it to display a CRUD similar to this

[image]

I'm stuck there. Without the CRUD it'll be difficult to manage the USERS.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As i can see from screenshot there is route _/user/admin_ which, by its description, should display crud page. Did you try it ?

Comment: Yes I tried that.. Then I get a #403 Forbidden, you are not allowed to perform this action (even though I'm logged in as Admin)

Comment: From module documentation: `Log in as admin using neo/neo (change it!)`. I've tried it on [module demo page](http://yii2.amnahdev.com/user) and page _/user/admin_ became available after I logged in with this credentials

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to redefine the controller too. You need a new controller derived form the original controller for correctly addressing  the new  CRUD element.

I suppose your controller is in backend and is named `user` otherwise change properly the following example (part of `config/main.php`):

```
'user' => [
    ...     

    'controllerMap' => [
        'user'  => 'backend\controllers\user', 
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to Controller in backend

```
public function init()
{
     $user_id = Yii::$app->getUser()->id;
     if($user_id){
        $user = \amnah\yii2\user\models\User::findOne($user_id);
         if ($user->can("admin")) {
             // do something
         }else{
             throw new HttpException(403, 'You are not allowed to perform this action.');
            }
        }else{
            throw new HttpException(403, 'You are not allowed to perform this action.');
        }
      parent::init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click the link `/user/admin`

You'll get CRUD for users.